# Does ffmpeg have a configuration file?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using a lot the ffmpeg program, I want to configure ffmpeg on linux so that it always hides banner (option -hide_banner) to reduce text output. I cannot seem to find anything that would tell me where this file should be and how it should be named so that ffmpeg will look at it every time it is run.

Comment: Why not create an alias? e,g, `alias ffnb="ffmpeg -hide_banner"` Search on SU for how to make it permanent.

Comment: yes, this seems like a smart workaround. i put my aliases in ~/.bash_aliases - which is by default sourced by ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ffmpeg does not use a configuration file post-install.

lots of ways to build ffmpeg, but generally you have to configure everything **before** install.

for example, with `brew` (macOS package manager) you have to edit the following file to supply your `--enable or --disable` args BEFORE INSTALLING.

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/ffmpeg.rb`

if you didn't get your args in on your original install, then you need to uninstall and re-install again with your desired options and args.

also: instead of supplying your options (`--with-webp` for example) from the CLI during install, you can write them in `ffmpeg.rb`.